# Iterate over 2D array of booleans and return an incremented value based on true/false

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean, increment

I'm trying to return a "matrix" or a 2D array where the boolean value turns into a number from 1-4 based on how many "true" values are next to it. I tried a different approach previously, represented by the current code below.

**The Problem:**

> When matrix = [[true, false, false], [false, true, false],[false, false, false]]
>
> the output should be [[1, 2, 1],[2, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1]]

**My Code:**

```js
function minesweeper(matrix) {
    for( var i =0; i < matrix.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++){
            if(matrix[i] && matrix[i][j] == true){
                matrix[i][j] = 2;
            }else {
                matrix[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

**My Errors/results:**

> Input matrix: [[true,false,false],[false,true,false],[false,false,false]]
>
> Output: [[2,1,1], [1,2,1], [1,1,1]]
>
> Expected Output: [[1,2,1], [2,1,1], [1,1,1]]
>
> Input matrix: [[false,false,false],  [false,false,false]]
>
> Output:[[1,1,1],  [1,1,1]]
>
> Expected Output:[[0,0,0], [0,0,0]]
>
> Input matrix: [[true,false,false,true],  [false,false,true,false],  [true,true,false,true]]
>
> Output:[[2,1,1,2],  [1,1,2,1],  [2,2,1,2]]
>
> Expected Output:[[0,2,2,1],  [3,4,3,3],  [1,2,3,1]]

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're having? Can you be more specific than "what's wrong with my code?"

Comment: @Necoras I am just trying to figure out how to turn boolean values into numbers and increment them properly based on true/false. My previous code was no-where near close to what I needed.

Comment: Boolean values are already numbers: 0 - false, and 1 - true. As for figuring out how to properly map the nearby true/false values to 1-4, I suspect that's the point of your assignment, so I'll leave figuring out the logic there to you. However, I will point out that you're modifying the initial `matrix` and returning that rather than storing your new (1-4) values in a new matrix variable. That will never give you the correct values because by the time you try to calculate the second value you've changed the initial matrix to be different from the starting conditions.

Comment: @Necoras Thank you for that help! I knew they already had 0 and 1, I wasn't sure if there was an extra step to allow for incrementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: It wasn't clear from your question whether you wanted to check 4 directions (e.g. north, west, south and east) or 8 directions (north, northwest, west, southwest, south, southeast, east and northeast). My initial answer was for 4 directions. However, I know see from your expected results that you likely wanted 8 directions, so I have re-written my answer for that scenario.**

There is a problem with the way you have asked the question. You talk about changing the original matrix, rather than, e.g., returning a new matrix with the results. If you actual change the matrix *while you are still processing it*, then you will probably end up changing some values before you've actually analyzed them. For instance, if you analyze the top left cell, find out that it's true, and then increment the cell to the right *in the same original table*, then the 2nd cell will no longer be the `true` or `false` value that it originally had, but rather will now be whatever you assigned to that cell (??? `false` plus 1 ??? or whatever). Thus, you really should leave your original matrix untouched and return a *new* table with the addition results from your analysis. (This touches on the issue of data immutability, but that's a discussion for another day.)

In any case, one approach to solving this is start with a results table the same size as the original matrix table, but with all values initially set to zero. Then you can iterate through all cells in the input table, adding 1 to positions in the results table that are to the right of, below, to the left of, and above the initial corresponding cell in the input table. However, you have to make sure that the results table position you're trying to add one to is actually in the table, i.e. not off the edge (e.g. not above or to the left of the upper left cell).

```js
function minesweeper(matrix) {
  const numRows = matrix.length, numCols = matrix[0].length; // determine matrix size
  const dirs = [[1,0],[1,1],[0,1],[-1,1],[-1,0],[-1,-1],[0,-1],[1,-1]];
  // coordinate changes for all 8 directions
  
  const results = matrix.map(row => row.map(cell => 0)); // initiate results table with 0s
  matrix.forEach((rowOfCells, matrixRowNum) => { // for each row
    rowOfCells.forEach((cell, matrixColNum) => { // for cell in each row
      if (cell) { // if that cell contains a true value
        dirs.forEach(dir => { // iterate through all dir'ns
          const resultsRowNum = matrixRowNum + dir[0]; // vertical position in results table
          const resultsColNum = matrixColNum + dir[1]; // horizontal position in results table
          if (
            resultsRowNum >= 0       &&
            resultsRowNum <  numRows &&
            resultsColNum >= 0       &&
            resultsColNum <  numCols
          ) { // if this is a valid position in the results table, i.e. not off the edge
            results[resultsRowNum][resultsColNum] += 1; // then increment the value found there
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
  return results;
}


let matrix;

matrix = [[true,false,false],[false,true,false],[false,false,false]];
console.log(JSON.stringify(matrix));
console.log(JSON.stringify(minesweeper(matrix)));

console.log('');

matrix = [[false,false,false], [false,false,false]];
console.log(JSON.stringify(matrix));
console.log(JSON.stringify(minesweeper(matrix)));

console.log('');

matrix = [[true,false,false,true], [false,false,true,false], [true,true,false,true]];
console.log(JSON.stringify(matrix));
console.log(JSON.stringify(minesweeper(matrix)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function minesweeper(matrix) {
var solution=[];
for( var i =0; i < matrix.length; i++){
    var inner=[];
    solution.push(inner);
    for(var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
        var count=0;
        if(matrix[i] && matrix[i][j]) count++;//at this position
        if(matrix[i] && matrix[i][j-1]) count++;//one left
        if(matrix[i] && matrix[i][j+1]) count++;//one right
        if(matrix[i-1] && matrix[i-1][j]) count++;//one above
        if(matrix[i+1] && matrix[i+1][j]) count++;//one below
        inner.push(count);
    }
}
return solution;
}
```

You need to create another array to resolve to your values.

http://jsbin.com/siquxetuho/edit?console

Comment: Thanks for this, it makes so much more sense! I was trying to increment the matrix by  matrix[i+1][j+1]. I'm trying to understand this looping through.. if j is of matrix[0].length, doesn't that refer to i? I think that's my confusion - trying to understand how j becomes the second row, and so forth

Comment: By the way, I tried this solution and it's throwing an error still. Input:
matrix: [[true,false,false], 
 [false,true,false], 
 [false,false,false]]
Output:
[[1,3,1], 
 [3,1,2], 
 [1,2,1]]
Expected Output:
[[1,2,1], 
 [2,1,1], 
 [1,1,1]]

Input:
matrix: [[false,false,false], 
 [false,false,false]]
Output:
[[1,1,1], 
 [1,1,1]]
Expected Output:
[[0,0,0], 
 [0,0,0]]